# Foreign key to assotiation table

Tags: sql, database-design, foreign-keys, rdbms

Is it OK to use a reference to a many-to-many association table or explicit FK's are better?

Let's assume we have some many-to-many model like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Project (
  id int NOT NULL,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE Programmer (
  id int NOT NULL,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE Project_Programmer_Association(
  id int NOT NULL,
  project_id int,
  programmer_id int,
  .... (probably some other data)
  FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES Project (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (programmer_id) REFERENCES Programmer(id)
);
CREATE TABLE Task (
  id int NOT NULL,
  project_programmer_id int,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (project_programmer_id) REFERENCES Project_Programmer_Association(id)
);
```

Within Project and Programmer table there are some data, required for the Task, so I need references to both tables. My question is: Should I use this reference in Task

```
CREATE TABLE Task (
  id int NOT NULL,
  project_programmer_id int,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (project_programmer_id) REFERENCES Project_Programmer_Association(id)
);
```

or two explicit keys will be better (exept of additional join absence)

```
CREATE TABLE Task (
  id int NOT NULL,
  project_id int,
  programmer_id int,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES Project (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (programmer_id) REFERENCES Programmer(id)
);
```

Comment: `FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES Persons(Project)`needs a column `Project_id`in that table

Comment: Tables represent relation(ship)s/associations--which constitute the state of the business. FKs (wongly but ubiquitously called "relationships") & other constraints express constraints on table values--for the DBMS to disallow invalid states. After you have tables, declare FKs & other constraints that aren't implied by others that you declared. PS A FK has a table & list of columns reference a table & list of columns.  It says subrows must appear elsewhere. You can't declare a FK from columns that aren't in a table. So your last example's FKs don't make sense. What are you trying to express?

Comment: Is Persons(Project_Programmer_Association) (which makes no sense) supposed to be Project_Programmer_Association(project_id) (which still makes no sense)? Again, what are you trying to express? PS What information modeling & database design textbook are you following & where are you stuck applying it? Otherwise your question just asks us to (re)write one.

Comment: You are right guys. I've updated example, sorry for confusing code. Just waned to express an idea and didn't see the mistakes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would prefer the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE Project (
  id int NOT NULL,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE Programmer (
  id int NOT NULL,
  ....
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
CREATE TABLE Project_Programmer_Association(
  project_id int,
  programmer_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY(project_id, programmer_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES Project,
  FOREIGN KEY (programmer_id) REFERENCES Programmer
);
CREATE TABLE Task (
  id int NOT NULL,
  project_id int,
  programmer_id int,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (project_id, programmer_id) REFERENCES Project_Programmer_Association
);
```

since it has the following advantages: no unnecessary key for `Project_Programmer_Association`, referential integrity guaranteed for `Task`; the possibility of joining directly `Tasks` with `Project_Programmer_Association`, `Project` and `Programmer`. Note that in the case for which there is only a task for each couple programmer-project (and only in that case) than you can remove also the `id` of Task and make the primary key the other two attributes.

Comment: Thanks. I like this approach more.

Answer (score 1):

The right question isn't "which is better", but "which represents your data".

If `Project_Programmer_Association` doesn't hold any data of its own, it may be redundant to keep it, and you could get away with foreign keys to the project and the programmer.

If it could hold data, and more specifically, if a project and a programmer can have several associations (e.g., Bob is the lead developer in project X but just a consultant in project Y), you most definitely need a foreign key to the association itself in order to properly represent your data model.

Comment: In case of additional data in assotiation table I agree. But only in case of these data are required for Task. For example I only need to select Tasks from projects with specific customers that have been done by programmers with specific skills. Type of association (role of programmer) can be used in another table, but in this particular relation I don't need such information and therefore don't want to expose relations betwean other tables.